# Inter Component Event Binding In Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a master component and many child components in an Angular application. I am rendering the child component using . Something like this.

```
<body class="nav-md">
    <mainComponent></mainComponent>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
```

My main component has a search box and a button. I want to call functions of my child component when I click the button in mainComponent. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add HTMl\TS code of main component and child components, so that any one can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ViewChild](http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/) in this case.

Example:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from '../child.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'mainComponent',
    template: '<search (onSearch)="onSearch($event)"></search><child-component></child-component>',
})
export class MainComopnent{
    // ViewChild takes a class type or a reference name string.
    // Here we are using the type
    @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;

    onSearch(search: string) {
        this.child.say(search);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'child-component'
})
export class ChildComponent {
    say(something: string) {
        console.log(something);
    }
}
```